# ionic 3 dictionary with users

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, ionic3, angularfire2

i'm building a dictionary whereby users register and submit words using ionic 3 and firebase, my problem is users can only see their own submitted words in a list, so i want them to see all words submitted by other users

how do i implement  it? below is the code to get list

```
 dictionaryListRef$: FirebaseListObservable<DictionaryItem[]>

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private database: AngularFireDatabase,
    public authData: AuthProvider
  ) {
    // Get current user Id
    var currentUserId = this.authData.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;

    // Point dictionaryListRef$ at firebase user -> 'dictionary-list' node.

    this.dictionaryListRef$ = this.database.list(`${currentUserId}/dictionary-list`);
```

Comment: Seems like you should eliminate the use of the current user id and instead perform a query that retrieves everything in your database instead.  Which may not scale very well.

Comment: Yeah I would agree with Doug, if you want to do a very naive implementation you can just make "shared" list where everyone can write to and read from. Its not secure but if you are not building high scale and super secure type of app that should work.

Comment: How? Can you please give me example